# very unexpected IndentationError: unexpected indent in django urls.py

Tags: python, django, indentation, django-urls

This is urls.py for django project here all things are fine:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]
```

but when I add my app url:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('movie/', include('movie.urls')),

]
```

it says

```
File "/storage/emulated/0/netflix/movie/urls.py", line 5
    urlpatterns = [
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: I would guess there is somewhere a non-printable character or something like that. The paste code looks okish (to me)

Comment: Delete all your whitespace by hand, and then add a new tab. Sometimes Python gets confused with spaces, and since they don't display differently to tabs, that can often be the source of problems.

Answer (score -1):

urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', views.index, name='main-view'),]

try using name or relaunch the server